# How to change a MACRO definition at runtime

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, macros

Say I have a Macro definition something like below:

`#define info <TLS slot for thread>.info`

if the TLS area is not defined for the thread, it needs to be

```
info_t info;

void foo()
{
    info.details = 0;
    ....
}
```

How can I change the definition of info at runtime so that it's either pointing to the MACRO value or the declaration depending on the thread?

It is a multi threaded environment.

We are using info in function foo() and this code can't be changed. Is there a way this can be set to point to the macro or declaration as needed?. We can rename the Macro and decl if needed.

Comment: What do you mean with "runtime"? Macros are evaluated even before the actual compilation - that's why it is called **pre**processing. That is explained in every introduction to C programming.

Comment: "MACRO" and "runtime" are incompatible terms.

Comment: I don't think you can do that but I have been wrong before  :)

Answer (score 2):

Macros in C are processed at *compile time* by the preprocessor.  The macro no longer exists after the code is compiled (after it's precompiled, actually).  So it's impossible to modify a macro at run time.

Instead of a macro, you should have a global array where each element contains data for a particular thread and operate on that.

Comment: What if a Macro is calling a function which will tell us if the thread TLS slot is initialized or not. Can we use some kind of conditional Macro at all?

Comment: @Rach Why do you think you *need* a `macro` to begin with? Any code that uses a macro can be rewritten without it, by simply expanding the macro inline. So, write the code without macros, first, and only *then* think whether a macro helps at all.